# Nuclide + Atom failed to find symbol with ctags

Tags: atom-editor, remote-server, ctags, nuclide-editor

So I've installed Facebook's Nuclide on top of my Atom editor.
Seems it provides many features.
My problem is that when I setup a remote project folder, I cannot get find symbol functioning any more.

The `alt+cmd+g` will through errors instead of generating ctags file in the project folder.
I ssh to the server and manually `ctags -R .` in the folder.
However, inside Atom/Nuclide, `cmd+shift+r` complains no tags file...

Please help. Any clues welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is provided by the symbols-view package, which ships as part of Atom. Unfortunately it reads from the filesystem directly, so it is not compatible with Nuclide's remote connection. There has been some talk of refactoring it to use Atom's service-hub (which is how Atom packages are supposed to talk to each-other).

If that happens, Nuclide could provide it with the information from outline view and it would be able to work remotely. The functionality would not be exactly the same but for most purposes it would be fine.

However, nobody has yet put in the resources to drive the refactoring home. [Here](https://github.com/atom/symbols-view/pull/204) is a recent effort; I hope it is completed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It clears my question. Since symbols-view reads from fs, what if I manually copy tags file to my local machine? Will it work? And if so, where should I put it? Thanks again.

Comment: That might work, but I don't know anything about the inner workings of the symbols-view package so I'm really not sure.

Comment: Thanks, Nat. Marking as answered.